# If a value is in the 2nd slot of a 2-length tuple

Tags: python, django

I've got a tuple like this:

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('1', 'first'),
    ('2', 'second'),
    ('3', 'third'),
    ('4', 'fourth'),
    ('5', '5th'),
    ('6', 'sixth'),
    ('7', 'seventh')
)
```

If a value is in the 2nd slot of the tuple (first, second etc..) do nothing. But if it isn't, change it to an empty string:

```
via = some_string
for a, b in CATEGORY_CHOICES:
    if via == b:
        break
```

So i've done the first bit (check to see if `via` equals one of the `b` values), but I'm not sure what to do once via has gone through all the `b` values and doesn't equal any of them. At that point I want assign an empty string to `via`. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the assignment to the empty string in the `else` clause of the `for`:

```
via = some_string
for a, b in CATEGORY_CHOICES:
    if via == b:
        break
else:
    via = ''
```

Control only flows to the `else` if the `for` loop finishes *cleanly*, which in this case means `break` was not executed.

---

More so, Python's [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) could also come in handy here:

```
via = some_string
if not any(via==b for _, b in CATEGORY_CHOICES):
    via = ''
```

As with the first approach, `any` short-circuits once a match is found and the `if` condition fails, otherwise, the assignment is performed.

Comment: `print CATEGORY_CHOICES[zip(*CATEGORY_CHOICES)[-1].index('target_string')]`